Help needed for assessing if given process is m.d.s
From Hayashi's Econometrics:

Example 2.4 (p. 101) (a white noise process that is not strictly stationary): Let $w$ be a random variable uniformly distributed in the
interval $(0, 2\pi)$, and define $z_{i} = \cos{(iw)}\ (i = 1, 2,
> \ldots)$. It can be shown that $\mathbb{E}(z_{i}) = 0$,
$\operatorname{Var}(z_{i}) = \frac{1}{2}$, and
$\operatorname{Cov}(z_{i}, z_{j}) = 0$ for $i \neq j$. So $\{z_{i}\}$
is white noise. However, clearly, it is not an independent white noise
process. It is not even strictly stationary.
Martingale Difference Sequences (p. 104) A vector process $\{\boldsymbol{g}_{i}\}$ with $\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{g}_{i}) =
> \boldsymbol{0}$ is called a martingale difference sequence (m.d.s.) or
martingale differences if the expectation conditional on its past
values, too, is zero: $\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{g}_{i} \mid
> \boldsymbol{g}_{i-1}, \boldsymbol{g}_{i-2}, \ldots) = \boldsymbol{0}$
for $i \geq 2.$
QUESTION FOR REVIEW (p. 108) (Forecasting white noise) For the white noise process of Example 2.4, $\mathbb{E}(z_{i}) = 0$. What is
$\mathbb{E}(z_{i} \mid z_{1})$ for $i \geq 2$? Hint: You should be
able to forecast the future exactly if you know the value of $z_{1}$.
Is the process an m.d.s? [Answer: No.]

Solution attempt:
$F_{z_{1}}(z) = P(z_{1} < z) = P(\cos{(w)} < z) = 2P(\arccos{(z)} < w < \pi) = 1 - \frac{\arccos{(z)}}{\pi}$;
$f_{z_{1}}(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F_{z_{1}}(z) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}}1_{(-1, 1)}{(z)}$;
$\mathbb{E}[z_{i}^{k} \mid z_{1} = z] = \mathbb{E}[\cos^{k}{(iw)} | \cos{(w)} = z] = \mathbb{E}[\cos^{k}{(iw)}| w = \arccos{(z)}] = \cos^{k}{(i\arccos{(z)})}$;
$\operatorname{Var}[z_{i} \mid z_{1} = z] = \mathbb{E}[z_{i}^{2} \mid z_{1} = z] - \mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{1} = z]^{2} = 0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{Var}[z_{i} \mid z_{1}] = 0$;
$\mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{1}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\cos{(iw)} | \cos{(w)} = z] f_{z_{1}}(z) dz = \frac{\sin{(i\pi)}}{i\pi} = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$;
$\mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{i-1}, \ldots, z_{1}] = \mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{1}] = 0$.
Isn't this process m.d.s., then? Any help spotting a mistake or lack of understanding would be greatly appreciated!

If you know $z_1$, then you know $\omega=\cos^{-1}(z_1)$ up to a set of two values -- eg, if $z_1=1/2$ then $\omega$ is either $\pi/3$ or $2\pi-\pi/3$.
Conditional on $z_1$ you know $z_2=\cos(2\omega)$ up to two values: either $\cos 2\pi/3=-0.5$ or $\cos (4\pi-2\pi/3)=-0.5$. These turn out to be the same; they always will be.
So $$E[z_i|\textrm{history}]=E[z_i|z_1]=\cos (i\cos^{-1}z_1)\neq 0$$
What is zero is the linear projection of $z_i$ on to its history. The $z_i$ are all uncorrelated, and in fact $z_i=T_i(z_1)$ where $T_i$ are the Chebyshev polynomials, but they aren't independent.
It's a trick question in a sense: if you didn't know how the $z_i$ were encoded, it would be a martingale difference sequence, but because you do know the encoding it isn't. The important point is that the history of a martingale really is the whole history, and that actually matters mathematically.

Thanks for your answer, I guess I get it now! It seems like I mixed up my definitions: the second to last step is actually $\mathbb{E}[h(z_{1})]$ with $h(z) = \mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{1} = z]$, and not $ \mathbb{E}[z_{i} \mid z_{1}]$ as I intended, what a mess!
